# Send page link in photo message on facebook

Tags: php, facebook, sdk

Need a help to be able to put the link to my page on the image that I am sending.

More than any way I can.

```
$photo = $facebook->api('/386987198043365/photos', 'POST',
    array(
        'source' => '@' . realpath('photos/601634_542276699138472_444978009_n.jpg'),
        'message' => 'Like this › @[305610509557745:0]'
    )
);
```

The image sends, the more the problem that the message looks like.

"Like this ›" and does not show the link of the page. Could someone help me!

Comment: did you found a solution for the "like this [pagelink]" ?